# How to stop the "yes" command from repeating other command?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, command

I used the command to try to make an automated way to answer the prompt in a certain command, now that command, will repeat indefinitely in the terminal even without using the yes command.

I'm not sure which one caused it, but I used the yes commands in several ways to try to make it work, such as

```
yes y | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager
yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager
yes $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager | yes
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager << yes
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager <<< yes
```

now, whenever I run the command `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager`, it outputs

```
/Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager: line 2414: y: command not found
/Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager: line 2415: y: command not found
/Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager: line 2416: y: command not found
...
```

How do I stop it ?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: When you repost there, you need to provide more details. I can't understand what you did, but there's no way you can make the command behave differently when you run it without `yes`.

Comment: You should show in your question the command you typed and the output you get. It is unclear how you used the `yes` command and what command gets repeated.

Comment: @Bodo i'm sorry, i updated the question

Comment: @Barmar i'm sorry, if the question is misplaced :/

Comment: You didn't explain in how exactly you used `yes`. Did you enter a command line that contains `yes`? Did you modify a script? What is in the lines 2414 etc of the script?

Answer (score 2):

I just realized that doing one of these command

```
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager << yes y
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager <<< yes y
```

screwed up the sdkmanager file, and now it contains just the letter y 55.3 million times

I just need to reinstall android sdk again

Comment: If you have lines containing `y` appended to the fie, I guess it might have been something like `yes >> $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager`. If it contains only lines with `y` it may have been `yes > $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager`

Comment: thanks bro, i should be careful next time i copy paste a command from the internet :D

Comment: Neither of those should have done that.  `<<<` and `<<` are both redirectors for standard input (stdin).  There must have been an additional command, perhaps an `echo` somewhere?  https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents

Comment: probably yes @jnovack, i remember using an echo in those commands several times